# OpenCV Error when running image_transport republish node

Tags: image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have an Ubuntu 11.10 and Ros electric.

I try to convert an Compressed image that comes from axis_camera to image, I have used :
rosrun image_transport republish compressed in:=/axis_camera _image_transport:=compressed raw out:=/axis_camera/image

And I got this error:

OpenCV Error: Null pointer (NULL array pointer is passed) in cvGetMat, file
/home/parisa/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp,
line 2382
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():/home/parisa/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp,line 2382:
error: (-27) NULL array pointer is passed in function cvGetMat

Aborted

Actually, there is no such file or directory in my laptop /home/parisa/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp
Anybody can help me?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29725/opencv-error-when-running-image_transport-republish-node/) by [Parisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/1846/parisa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-03-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similiar problem while working on the android_core/android_camera_tutorial. It turned out that some malformed images were being published. I suggest looking into the axis_camera node and make sure that it's publishing good data.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1